Clerk Expo error 422 - email_code does not match one of the allowed values for parameter stratergy
I followed the clerk expo docs and created a email+paswword sign up component in react native. The following options are enabled for sign up in the dashboard -


Despite passing both the values - email and password to the prepareEmailAddressVerification function I am still getting error -
{
  "status": 422,
  "clerkError": true,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "form_param_value_invalid",
      "message": "is invalid",
      "longMessage": "email_code does not match one of the allowed values for parameter strategy",
      "meta": {
        "paramName": "strategy"
      }
    }
  ]
}


I can't figure out why this error is coming up.
Code -
The auth function is here -
const onSignUpPress = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await signUp.create({
        emailAddress,
        password,
      });
      await signUp.prepareEmailAddressVerification({ strategy: "email_code" });
      setPendingVerification(true);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorList(err?.errors);
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
  };

  const onPressVerify = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const completeSignUp = await signUp.attemptEmailAddressVerification({
        code,
      });

      if (completeSignUp.status === 'complete') {
        await setActive({ session: completeSignUp.createdSessionId });
        router.replace('/');
      } else {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(completeSignUp, null, 2));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
  };


And the code for the sign up view is -
{!showLogin && 
      <View style={styles.subContainer}>
      {!pendingVerification && (
        <>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            value={emailAddress}
            placeholder="Email..."
            onChangeText={(email) => setEmailAddress(email)}
          />
          {errorList.map((error, index) => 
            error.meta.paramName === 'email_address' && (
              <Text key={index} style={styles.errorText}>{error.message}</Text>
            )
          )}
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={password}
            placeholder="Password..."
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)}
          />
          {errorList.map((error, index) => 
            error.meta.paramName === 'password' && (
              <Text key={index} style={styles.errorText}>{error.message}</Text>
            )
          )}
          <Button style={styles.button} title="Sign Up" onPress={onSignUpPress} />
        </>
      )}
      {pendingVerification && (
        <>
          <TextInput
            value={code}
            placeholder="Code..."
            onChangeText={(code) => setCode(code)}
          />
          <Button title="Verify Email" onPress={onPressVerify} />
        </>
      )}
        <View>
          <Text>Already have an account?</Text>
           
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pillButton} onPress={()=>setShowLogin(true)}>
            <Text style={styles.pillButtonText}>Log In</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>}


I was having the same exact issue and I:

created a new Clerk app in the dashboard
updated the EXPO_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY in my .env file
re-ran the expo app and went through the sign up flow

and it worked after that. not sure what happened!

Yes same thing happened with me as well
